# How can I pass Resources to ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

This is a situation where you need to pass `Resources` to the `properties` of the `ViewModel`, so you have to pass `Resources` as an `argument` to the `constructor`.

***ViewModel***

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(private val resources: Resources) : ViewModel(){
    private var _part :MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    private var _list : MutableLiveData<List<String>> = MutableLiveData(arrayListOf())
    private val workoutListSource : WorkoutListSource by lazy { WorkoutListLocalSource(resources) }

    val list = _list
    val part = _part

    fun setList(part : String) {
        _part.value = part
        when(_part.value) {
            "CHEST" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.CHEST)
            "BACK" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.BACK)
            "LEG" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.LEG)
            "SHOULDER" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.SHOULDER)
            "BICEPS" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.BICEPS)
            "TRICEPS" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.TRICEPS)
            "ABS" -> _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.ABS)
        }
    }
}
```

***interface***

```
interface WorkoutListSource {
    fun getWorkoutListByPart(type: BodyType) : List<String>
}
```

***implementation of the interface***

```
class WorkoutListLocalSource(_resources: Resources) : WorkoutListSource {
    private val resource: Resources = _resources

    override fun getWorkoutListByPart(type: BodyType): List<String> {
        return resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId()).toList()
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote

But this code must be wrong.

The developer documentation says that the `ViewModel` should not reference the `Android platform`.

However, I am passing `Resources` as an `argument` in the `ViewModel`.

I think this part is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it correctly.

---

***UPDATED***

***Fragment***

```
class WorkoutListTabPageFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : FragmentWorkoutListTabPageBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    private val viewModel: WorkoutListViewModel by viewModels { WorkoutListViewModelFactory(resources) }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel. If your only constructor parameter is Application, you don't even need to create a factory for it.

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val resources = application.resources
    //...
}
```

And a code simplification tip:

```
fun setList(part : String) {
    _part.value = part
    _list.value = workoutListSource.getWorkoutListByPart(BodyType.valueOf(part))
}
```

Although I think having so many body parts (with possibly more to be added in the future) lends itself towards handling the types as data in a repository instead of hard-coding them as enum values. And either way, it's better to commit to using only enums or only Strings so you don't have to keep converting back and forth.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's something I don't understand, so let me ask you a question.

Why don't we need a `factory` if the only `constructor parameter` is `application`?

Comment: The default factory is able to handle empty constructors and constructors where the only parameter is Application if the ViewModel is an AndroidViewModel. The default factory is used if you pass no factory to `by viewModels()` or `ViewModelProvider()`. You can look at the source code of SavedStateViewModelFactory if you want to see how it works. It uses reflection to find a matching constructor.

Comment: Added fragment code that uses `viewmodel`. As you said, I don't need to use `viewModels()` in my case?

Comment: No, I said you don’t need to create a factory to pass to `viewModels()`.

Comment: Hmm...then I can just use private val viewModel: WorkoutListViewModel by viewModels() ? No need to pass the application argument?

Comment: Correct, nothing to pass

Comment: The `viewModel` class is supposed to receive `Application` as an argument, but how can I not pass the `application` as an argument when using `by viewModels()`?
Is this a special case or is it handled internally?

Comment: It is a special case. The default ViewModelFactory is able to instantiate it via reflection. It specifically can handle empty constructors, or constructors with only Application and/or SavedStateHandle as the only constructor arguments. Any other combination of constructor arguments would require you to create your own factory. (I haven’t seen this in the documentation anywhere. I only know by word of mouth and reading the Jetpack source code.)

Comment: thanks. I barely understood I'm sorry, but I'll ask a little more.
You recommended using `repositories` in your answer. You mean `database`, right? Then, from my little knowledge, I know that there is a way to use the internal database of the `device` and the database of the `server`.
I'm trying to show the user a list of choices like the code in the `OP`. I need to store this in a `database`, which one should I use?

Comment: Repository is just a generic term that could refer to a database, files, a web server, etc. in this case, based on the scale of what you’re doing I think I would personally use JSON files to define the structure, where the values act as keys for String resources. I don’t have a lot of experience in this area though so that may not be the best way.

Comment: ok, thanks for answering so many questions

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModelFactory class and pass in the starting data for the ViewModel.

[ViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model#7)

```
class MyFragmentViewModelFacotry(private val resources: Resrouces) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
  override fun<T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyFragmentViewModel::class.java)) {
      return MyFragmentViewModel(resources) as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
  } 
}
```

ViewModel

```
class ViewModel(private val resources: Resources) : ViewModel() {
   ...
}
```

Creating a ViewModel with a ViewModelFactory, in the Activity or Fragment run the following

```
val viewModelFactory: MyViewModelFactory = MyViewModelFactory(resources)
val viewModel =  ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```